# Large Optimized IO processing in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, io

An input n of the order 10^18 and output should be the sum of all the numbers whose set bits is only 2. For e.g. n = 5 setbit is 101--> 2 set bits. For n = 1234567865432784,How can I optimize the below code?

```
class TestClass 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        long N,s=0L;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            N=sc.nextLong();
            for(long j = 1; j<=N; j++)
            {
                long b = j;
                int count = 0;
                while(b!=0)
                {
                    b = b & (b-1);
                    count++;
                }

                if(count == 2)
                {
                    s+=j;
                    count = 0;
                }
                else
                {   
                    count = 0;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(s%1000000007);
            s=0L;
    }

}
```

Comment: [look at this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: Did you just edit the question you asked to make it an entirely different question?

Comment: I typed a wrong question first Leo, please help me in this question.

Comment: I need help with the fast IO techniques to read large inputs and print large outputs. Need help in that too.

Answer (score 1):

Java has a function

```
if (Integer.bitCount(i) == 2) { ...
```

However consider a bit: that are a *lot* of numbers to inspect.

What about *generating* all numbers that have just two bits set?

Setting the i<sup>th</sup> and j<sup>th</sup> bit of `n`:

```
int n = (1 << i) | (1 << j); // i != j
```

Now consider 31² steps, not yet 1000 with N steps.

As this is homework my advise:

> Try to turn the problem around, do the least work, take a step back, find the intelligent approach, search the math core. *And enjoy.*

Next time, do not spoil yourself of success moments.

Comment: I need help with the fast IO techniques to read large inputs and print large outputs. i think your approach to this problem is elegant. i am trying to implement that, i may ask for little more explanation if I don't get it.

Comment: @sagnikDas I actually provided the implementation described here in my answer 3 hours ago. I dont know what you mean by IO. I cant find anything IO related in your question.

Comment: I understand in the question I specifically didn't mention about IO. I requested later, if we can use fast io techniques like BufferedReader or BufferedInputStream....to take inputs which i think are way more faster than Scanner. I need to know the implementation techniques

Comment: I hate it when someone gives a good answer to a particularly bad question, and the OP goes "no it doesn't fix my problem 100%" and doesn't upvote or tick it.

Comment: @LeoIzen thanks for the compassion. If it does not fit the OPs need, that's fine with me. Mind I did not give a full answer, and a "Try to ..." might sound a bit harsh. (I already have too many points, and one cannot win them all.)

Answer (score 1):

As you probably had enough time to think about Joop Eggen's suggestion,
here is how i would do it (which is what Joop described i think):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long n = sc.nextLong();

        long sum = 0;

        for (int firstBitIndex = 0; firstBitIndex < 64; firstBitIndex++) {
            long firstBit = 1L << firstBitIndex;
            if (firstBit >= n)
                break;
            for (int secondBitIndex = firstBitIndex + 1; secondBitIndex < 64; secondBitIndex++) {
                long value = firstBit | (1L << secondBitIndex);
                if (value > n)
                    break;
                sum += value;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum % 1000000007);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoopEggen You are right, i forgot the "L". I have modified the code. One has to be very careful anyway, because the last bit is going to toggle the sign which will certainly interfere with the >n comparison. So sad Java has no proper unsigned type...

Comment: On the sign: N = 10^18 = 10^3^6 <= 2^10^6 = 2^60 so a bound of 61 or 63 (for no explanation needed) should suffice. No need to correct, as n given.

Comment: @JoopEggen oh yeah, forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

Java provides the class `BigInteger`, which includes a method `nextProbablePrime()`. This means you could do something like this:

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger(stringInputN);
BigInteger test = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
BigInteger total = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
while (test.compareTo(n) < 0){
    total = total.add(test);
    test = test.nextProbablePrime();
}
System.out.println(total);
```

This this has an extremely low probability of getting the wrong answer (but nonzero), so you might want to run it twice just to doublecheck. It should be faster than manually iterating it by hand though.